# Always preflop all in with JJ+? cash game

Tags: nlhe, cash-game, pre-flop

Suppose you play 6 mx NLHE at around 50 cent BB, some guy raises and you reraise and he 4 bets, what do you do in general With hands AJ to AK and 1010 to AA?

If you shove AK, arent you always underdog?

Comment: That depends on the player. Is he tight, loose, aggressive, passive? What's his range?

Comment: IN general that is a pretty wide range of hands.  AK is not always an underdog to a 4 bet.  The title is JJ+ and content is different. Voting to close. Ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

The logic of the question is on the wrong basis whatsoever. Mathematics are essential to poker, but if you try to apply them without taking into account all the other parameters you end up with simplistic dogmas, such as "You never fold kings preflop" or "If I have an ace on the button, I must open" etc.

To try to approach your question, imagine a very loose player who opens every hand and 4bets 100% when he gets 3betted. In this extreme case, would you 5-bet shove with 99-TT-JJ? Now imagine the opposite scenario. A very tight-solid player, who rarely opens and has a very polarised 4bet range (AA, KK and some occasional bluffs). Would you 5-bet shove with JJ? And then there are infinite other kinds of players in between.

As you can see, there is no "rule" as to (or not to) shove JJ or AK preflop. You need to take into account dozens of other factors, including your opponent's range, your table image, the history between you two and many more to take your final decision.

Especially if you are moving to higher and higher stakes, when the game goes beyond "ABC poker by the book", you have to learn to adapt to new players and their strategies, as well as change your own style frequently, in order to become unpredictable and harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the opponent but in general in this situation I will be shipping with a wide range. JJ+ and AK at the very least.